# Image of conditional expectation in von Neumann algebra

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, operator-algebras, von-neumann-algebras

Let $\mathcal M$ be a finite von Neumann algebra and $\mathcal E:\mathcal M\to\mathcal N$ be the conditional expectation operator onto a von Neumann subalgebra. Suppose that we know $\|ex_ne\|_\infty\leq c$ for a fixed sequence $(x_n)\in \mathcal N$ and a projection $e\in\mathcal M$.

Is it true that $\sup_{n\geq 1}\|ax_na\|_\infty<\infty$ where $a:=\mathcal E(e)$ ?

Comment: The conclusion holds if $x_n$ are nonnegative. I guess $\|\cdot\|_\infty$ denotes the norm on the von Neumann algebra.

Comment: Yes. The conclusion holds if x-n s are non negative. I am actually interested in the general case!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This fails even in finite dimension. Let $M=M_2(\mathbb C)$, $N=\mathbb C\oplus\mathbb C$, and $\mathcal E$ the canonical pinching, that is
$$
\mathcal E\bigg(\begin{bmatrix} a&b\\c&d\end{bmatrix}\bigg)=\begin{bmatrix} a&0\\0&d\end{bmatrix}.
$$ Let
$$
x_n=\begin{bmatrix} n&0\\0&-n\end{bmatrix}\in N,\qquad\qquad e=\frac12\begin{bmatrix} 1&1\\1&1\end{bmatrix}. 
$$
Then
$ex_ne=0$ for all $n$, but since $\mathcal E(e)=\frac12\,I_2$,
$$
\|ax_na\|=\frac14\,\bigg\|\begin{bmatrix} n&0\\0&-n\end{bmatrix}\bigg\|=\frac n4. 
$$

Comment: Nice! If the sub von neumann algebra is a factor then can we produce a counterexamplle also?

Comment: I would think yes, but not entirely sure. I'll try to think about it.

Comment: Thank you once again for your answer. Is it true that there is a constant $C>0$. such that for any $\lambda>0$ there is a projection $e$ in hyperfine type $II_1$-factor such that $\sup\|ex_ne\|_\infty\leq \lambda$ and $\tau(1-e)\leq \frac{C}{\lambda}$? We can view $x_n$ as an element of type II_1 factor.

Comment: C is independent of lambda

Comment: My bad. But what prevents you from taking $e=0$ and $C=\lambda$?

Comment: I want some positive constant independent of $\lambda>0.$ That is the point. So we cannot take $C=\lambda$ as it will make $C$ dependent of $\lambda.$

Comment: Fair enough. Not at my sharpest today! :D

Comment: The sequence $(x_n)$ as you have given do not have this property if you condor the underlying von Neumann algebra to be $M_2(\mathbb C)$. But if we view it in hyperfine type II_1 factor, we may have this property for $(X_n)$

Comment: The example was very sharp! I am thinking around it for last two days!